# AlarmManager can't be cancelled in the Activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I need to start AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver, which starts the Service in the Activity.

When I do it like this:

```
  static int requestCode =12;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.car_search_activity);
        mContext=  this;
         alarms =  (AlarmManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(mContext,
                CarSearchResultsBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pi= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
                requestCode , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
        alarms.cancel(pi);
    }
```

But it is can't be cancelled in this way and continues executing, even I'm in another Activity

Answer (score 0):

You have different `requestCode` for the 2 `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)` calls.  The AlarmManager treats these as different PendingIntents.  Try saving the requestCode int as a static and using that as the requestCode for the PendingIntent.getBroadcast in onCreate and in onPause

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

Comment: thank you. I've done as you advices, but received the same result. I've added the edition to my question

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer**

Suggest you try following to simplify the logic: decouple the alarm from the activities and set it on an extended application class.

Create an application class with a static instance, so you can call:

```
MyApp.instance().startAlarm(MyBroadcastReceiver.class, 10 * 1000);
```

and

```
MyApp.instance().cancelAlarm(MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
```

where the alarm method implementations are:

```
   public void startAlarm(Class<?> clazz, int frequencyMs) {
      Context context = MyApp.instance();
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), frequencyMs, pi);
  }
  
  public void cancelAlarm(Class<?> clazz) {
      Context context = MyApp.instance();
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
      am.cancel(pi);
  }
```

The response code can be changed to any `int` as long as it is the same in both methods.

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Set the alarm in mirroring Activity lifecycle methods, i.e. either onCreate() + onStop() OR onResume() + onPause().

**Old answer**

In

```
 PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
    alarms.cancel(pi);
```

Does the `intent` parameter has the same configuration when you set the alarm as when you cancel it?

Also, I think you need to remove the call to `.cancel()` here:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

Only call `cancel` on the `AlarmManager`, your `alarms` variable.

Comment: Yes, Intent has the same configuration. I removed the cancel() call and using only alarms.cancel(pi); but the problem remains. Tell me please, should I re-create the AlarmManager instance to cancel or I can use those, with which I started the AlarmManager ?

Comment: just retrieve it via .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) where you need a reference.

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi Updated the answer with an approach that worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Gunnar Karlsson I have a similar use case.  Should the "NixApplication.instance();" you mention in the startAlarm and cancelAlarm methods be "MyApp.instance(), since you use "MyApp.instance..." to call the startAlarm and cancelAlarm methods?

Comment: @AJW yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Gunnar Karlsson I've created some Alarms in OneActivity and want to delete them in a SecondActivity.  Can I simply use getApplicationContext() for the first Alarm parameter rather than create a static instance in the application class?